# Use Facebook API to retrieve count of unread group messages for a group

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql, facebook-group

I'm trying to find a way to get a count of unread posts for groups, like the ones shown on the left hand-side menu of Facebook.com

I was able to find the reference to [Group table in FQL](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/group), but I can't see any field there representing the count of unread messages

Am I in the right place to find this data or is there some other way to retrieve it?

Answer (score 0):

This is available as the `unread` field of the Group in FQL or Graph API, but in FQL this is the [`group_member` table](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/group_member), not the `group` table.

To access the unread count of a group you'll need the `user_groups` [Permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) from the user.

Sample Graph API call:

`/me/groups?fields=unread`

Response:

```
{
  "data": [
       {
      "name": "Facebook Developers", 
      "version": 1, 
      "id": "146797922030397", 
      "unread": 11, 
      "bookmark_order": 1
    }, 
// snip
```

Sample FQL Query:
`select gid, unread from group_member where uid = me()`

Sample response:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "gid": "146797922030397", 
      "unread": 3


}
// removed other groups
```